# will weak_pointer.lock() increment the ref count of original shared_ptr which was used to create weak_ptr

Tags: c++, weak-ptr

As per my understanding, weak pointer is used to cyclic dependency problem occurs if we use all shared_ptr objects and if there is a cyclic dependency. Weak pointers are used to break the cycles. weak pointers achieves this by using lock() which will create shared pointer.

```
class A { shared_ptr<B> b; ... };
class B { weak_ptr<A>   a; ... };
shared_ptr<A> x(new A); // +1
x->b = new B;           // +1
x->b->a = x;            // No +1 here
```

But now assume that I created lock calling x->b->a.lock(), so ref count of x will become 2. and if x leaves the scope, still there will be memory leak right? Because I created a shared pointer using lock() and ref count became 2. Please let me know whether my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: When the object created by `lock()` is destroyed by its destructor, it decrements the count again.

Comment: What do you do with the return value of `lock()`?  If you ignore it, the lock is immediately removed again.

Comment: A fairly [simple sample program](https://ideone.com/3JQsaX) would show you what happens. the lock() becomes pretty-much worthless as you're using it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks WhozCraig. Assume that I was trying to access some member variable by using the pointer returned by lock(). At the end of the function, whether the lock will be removed first or whether operating system tries to free the memory pointed by shared_ptr (x). If operating system tries to free the memory pointed by shared_ptr (x), memory leak will happen. But how it is ensured that lock will be removed first

Comment: The temporary shared pointer returned from the `lock()` is being immediately released, and thus so is the reference count back to its original. If you want to extend the code presented to an alternate question you will have to do so in the question itself. With the code *as-written*, I'm not sure i understand what your question is at this point. (wouldn't be the first time for me).

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. A cyclic dependency that arise from the design and its inherent semantic constraints cannot in any case be fixed with any amount of weak references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two* distinct reference counts involved for a `shared_ptr` shared object:

- The number of references to the object, i.e. `shared_ptr` instances.
- The number of references to the **control block**, i.e. `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` instances.

A `weak_ptr` contributes only to the latter count. When all `shared_ptr` instances have been destroyed, the object deleter is called, which usually is the default one that destroys the object. The control block still exists if there are weak pointers. When also all weak pointers have been destroyed, the control block is destroyed.

So (ignoring possible optimization of caching object pointer directly in each `shared_ptr` instance), in your case you have `x` pointing (hidden for you) to the control block, which has a pointer to the `A` instance. And you have the `b` member of that instance pointing to a second control block, which has a pointer to a `B` instance. Finally that instance has a pointer to the control block that `x` points to, which is circular yes, but not a circularity of ownership.

Comment: That smart pointers keep a pointer to the object they point to isn't an optimization, it's by definition